# FineUploader: Add/change validation rules on onValidate/onValidateBatch callback

Tags: validation, fine-uploader

On a page, a fineUploader dropzone is created with some initial validation settings. Before the user hits the Upload button, a few validation settings may change. How to make fineUploader to replace the initial validation rules with the new ones?

I have an application that allows you to create ads of different sizes and i want to use the qq.ImageValidation to validate the image ad dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make fineUploader to replace the initial validation rules with the new ones?

You cannot. But you can call a function within the [`submit`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) event which can dynamically validate files, and set some "base" validators in the [`validation`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation-option) option.

```js
validation: {
// set default options such as making sure all uploads are images 
// or within a certain size.
},

onSubmit: function (id, name) {

   var file = this.getFile(id),
       validated = validate(file);
   if (validated) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

If this function returns `false`, then the item will **not** be marked as validated and not be uploaded. If this function returns `true`, then the validators you set in the options will be ran over the file(s) afterwards.

Comment: I have tried this, but to use qq.ImageValidation, i need access to the actual File that i want to validate. "item", the first argument from "onValidate: function (item, button)" is just an object with data about that file. As i can see, qq.ImageValidation accepts only a File or Blob for the first argument. How can i get it inside onValidate callback? Can i try to validate this inside onSubmit callback?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can get the file using `getFile(id)`, and get the `id` inside the `submit` callback.

Comment: you cannot do any validation in the `submit` event callback. for example, you don't have any access to a file's dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimensions"? You can get the file's information via the `getFile(id)` method during the `submit` callback.